# Android VM heap - heapsize. Is this normal?

Tags: android

```
ID       Heap Size     Allocated       Free      % Used  #Objects
1        7.383 MB      3.551 MB   3.832 MB      48.10%   65,709
```

That's what I see in DDMS. I have no sense of what's reasonable, but seems like a lot to me. I guess % used refers to percentage of heap size that allocated is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything strange with those values. The exact heap limit differs depending on screen size, but I think the minimum is 24 MB. I'd say the percentage refers to current heap limit. Note that heap limit will not be larger than it has to be. It might be 14 MB now but then it will grow if needed(to the maximum limit just mentioned).

This video explains a lot of good stuff about memory: http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=_CruQY55HOk